# QSplitter does not correctly set sizes

Tags: qt, qsplitter

I have a horizontal QSplitter with two widgets. I want to replace the right hand widget with a new one in a way that the proportions the user has set are maintained. Below is a simplified version of the code I currently have:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    splitter = new QSplitter(this);
    splitter->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);

    leftWidget = new QPushButton("left", splitter);
    rightWidget = new QPushButton("right", splitter);

    splitter->addWidget(leftWidget);
    splitter->addWidget(rightWidget);

    setCentralWidget(splitter);
}

void MainWindow::swapLayout()
{
    QList<int> sizes = splitter->sizes();

    rightWidget->deleteLater();
    splitter->update();

    rightWidget = new QPushButton("new right", splitter);

    splitter->addWidget(rightWidget);
    splitter->setSizes(sizes);
}
```

swapLayout() saves the sizes, removes the right widget, adds a new right hand widget and attempts to reset the sizes. However the left hand widget occupies 100% of the space. Without trying to restore the sizes the widgets both take up 50% of the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the actual order of operations is:

1. saving sizes of 2 widgets;
2. adding 3rd widget.
3. setting size for 3 widgets (and `sizes.at(2)` is `0` by default.
4. Deleting 2nd widget.

It caused by the fact that `deleteLater()` only schedules deleting, and actual deleting is processed after you exit `swapLayout()` method.  Try `delete rightWidget;` instead of `rightWidget->deleteLater();` if it possible. Or process events between deleting `rightWidget` and adding new one.

Comment: Thanks for this, the problem was deleteLater() not removing the widget there and then. In the end I've used the steps you listed in the order 1, 2, 4, 3 and also called hide on the widget before deleting just to be sure. Thanks again!